# how to remove the p html label that generated by the drupal CCK module

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, cck

I created an input textbox using the CCK module, but out the textbox content it added the

```
     <p>
```

label to it. How to remove it? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The p tag is generally added by the wysiwyg modules like CKEditor or TinyTiny MCE modules. You can set the type of tags that you want to use of text areas (or remove them) altogehter.

If you want more control also consider using [Semantic CCK](http://drupal.org/project/semantic_cck)

Answer (score 0):

It is probably added by either a wysiwyg editor, as Gokul says, or by an input filter being applied to the field as it is rendered. If you want it to just have whatever you entered, make sure neither is being applied to your field.